# jQuery .html() working OK, but JavaScript .innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm unable to find out the reason why `$('#valvonta_d').html(data);` is working, but `valvonta_div.innerHTML = data;` is not working at all.

I have some JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  valvonta = function() {
    var kaavio = 106;

    jQuery.post("hae_tilanteet.php", {
      kaavio: kaavio
    }).done(function(data) {
      // the following would work, but I prefer using JavaScript:
      // $('#valvonta_d').html(data);

      // this is not working
      var valvonta_div = document.getElementById('valvonta_d');
      valvonta_div.innerHTML = data;
    });
  };

  setTimeout(valvonta, 6000);
};
```

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="valvonta_d"></div>
```

Comment: Any error in the Console?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What exactly are you appending? There's no issue in the code you've shown.

Comment: ...and you're not invoking the `valvonta` function, so neither should be working. Is there a reason you've put the code in there?

Comment: @squint I added the last row.

Comment: @xms You'll have to elaborate on your post before we'll be able to help you directly, without just guessing. Saying "doesn't work" simply isn't detailed enough. There are too many possibilities. So... In exactly what way are the 2 results different? Different appearance? Different behavior? Can you provide or at least summarize the contents provided by `hae_tilanteet.php` as `data`?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes, in fact, the value of variable `data` is `<script>...</script>`. So, how should I use eval()?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console??? @xms

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt No, I do not think so.

Answer (score 0):

> the value of variable data is `<script>...</script>`.

`<script>` elements inserted via `innerHTML` [are intentionally disabled/ignored by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) out of concern for it potentially permitting cross-site scripting.

You'll have to evaluate them yourself by retrieving their contents in a separate step.

```
}).done(function(data) {
    var valvonta_div = document.getElementById('valvonta_d');
    valvonta_div.innerHTML = data;

    Array.from(valvonta_div.querySelectorAll('script')).forEach(function (script) {
        if (script.getAttribute('src')) return;

        // `(0, ...)` for global eval via indirect reference
        (0, eval)(script.textContent || '');
    });
});
```

---

Though, if you can, try to avoid the need to `eval()`.

In general at least, you should be able to define a generic form of the `<script>` as a `function`, included within the page prior to this.

```
function prepareVolvanta(kaavio, container) {
    // ...
}
```

Then, call that function when the content is ready.

```
var valvonta_div = document.getElementById('valvonta_d');
valvonta_div.innerHTML = data; // content markup only

prepareVolvanta(kaavio, valvonta_div);
```

---

Related: [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: How should I declare valvonta_div?

Comment: If I add `setTimeout(valvonta, 6000);` to inside of `.done(function(data)` it does not work anymore when using your code. Otherwise your code works fine.

Comment: I hadn't suggested that you move the `setTimeout`. There was a prior answer by another user that suggested something similar, though not quite that.

Comment: I modified my opening message, so now you see what I did mean.

Comment: @xms First, please don't edit your question in a way that knowingly breaks the code in the snippet. The comment was sufficient. – I understood what you meant, but I think you may be confusing my answer with a another post that was written and deleted by different user. I hadn't mentioned `setTimeout()` before these comments or suggested that it should be moved anywhere.